# The validity of lambda expression with omitted parameter list in C++23

Tags: c++, lambda, language-lawyer, c++23

According to [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/compiler_support), both gcc and clang have completed the implementation of [P1102R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2020/p1102r2.html) ("*Down with ()*!") recently, which means we can define lambda expressions more concisely in C++23.

But I found that they are inconsistent with a certain form:

```
auto l = []<auto> noexcept requires true {};
```

clang accepts this form, and gcc [rejects](https://godbolt.org/z/hxeGffMdT) its grammar.

Which compiler should I trust? Is this lambda well-formed or ill-formed in C++23?

### Update:

Perhaps because of the pressure of public opinion, clang quickly fixed the [49736](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49736) within five days after I reported it.

As I tried further, I accidentally found out that gcc also rejected the following valid form, which made me report the [99850](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=99850) and it was fixed after 2 weeks.

```
auto l = []<auto> requires true -> void {};
```

Comment: It doesn't look like this lambda has any real-life application. Adding the language-lawyer tag is probably a good idea.

Comment: I would not trust the implementation of any C++23 feature from a compiler that hasn't even finished C++20. Also, what command line option would you even use to access it?

Comment: @NicolBolas GCC & Clang trunk understand `-std=c++2b`.

Comment: "Perhaps because of the pressure of public opinion" -- +1 just for that joke.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Thanks for reminding me of how pointless this feature is.

The correct answer is: no, that's not a well-formed lambda. The grammar is defined in [[expr.prim.lambda.general]](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim.lambda.general):

[image]

In our case, to start with we have:

```cpp
[]<auto> noexcept requires true {};
```

- `[]` is the *lambda-introducer*
- `<auto>` matches `<template-parameter-list>` and now we know we're the 2nd kind *lambda-expression*. So grammatically, we're need to follow with a *requires-clause* (optionally) then a *lambda-declarator* then a *compound-statement*.
- `noexcept` does not match *requires-clause*, so now we're parsing a *lambda-declarator*. A *lambda-declarator* could start with `(parameter-declaration-clause)` but we don't have that, so we're just looking for *lambda-specifiers*. We consume the `noexcept` as part of *noexcept-specifier*.
- `requires true` does not fit either *attribute-specifier-seq* or *trailing-return-type* so we have neither of those, and now we're done with *lambda-specifiers* so we're done with *lambda-declarator*. At this point, we're looking for a *compound-statement*. But we don't have that, so this is an error.

Basically, there are two spots you can put a *requires-clause*: either directly after the template parameters or, *if we have function parameters*, after the *lambda-specifiers* after the function parameters. So this works:

```cpp
[]<auto> requires true noexcept {};
```

as does this:

```cpp
[]<auto>() noexcept requires true {};
```

as does this:

```cpp
[]<auto> requires true () noexcept requires true { };
```

But not the one in OP.

Also, don't write this.

Comment: I filed a [bug report](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=49736) for llvm this morning, but I am not 100% sure that it should be ill-formed. Thanks for letting me know I'm right.

Comment: An additional point: Would making it defined remove a wart, making the language more regular, and should it thus be defined? Contrived examples being contrived isn't all that surprising though.

Comment: @Deduplicator Should it? I mean, if you're at the point where you're already writing template parameters _and_ a noexcept-specifier _and_ a requires-clause, are you really harmed by having to provide an extra `()`?

Comment: @Barry Would it make it more regular? Is it unambiguous what it should do? Having a simple workaround at most lowers priority.

Comment: @Deduplicator: It was simply not considered worthwhile to make a complicated grammar to make a non-empty *lambda-specifiers* differentiate the two potential *requires-clause*s.

Comment: The observation that led to the current rule is that the requires-clause is either constraining the explicit template parameter list or the explicit function parameter list. As such, an explicit `<>` list can be followed by a requires-clause, and an explicit `()` list can be followed by a requires-clause. If you omit the explicit list, you can't include a requires clause for it.